# Finding and connecting with academic headhunters

Tags: research-process, job-search, united-kingdom

As a senior in my field, but very unhappy in my current institution, I am eager to move. My high REF score/productivity and ongoing Impact mean, even before grants, I cost less to employ on a fractional Chair, such as I currently hold, than I bring in. But there is a limit to how many fishing conversations I can have with colleagues elsewhere without these getting back to my current employer. Plus it becomes generally unprofessional.

So I am looking to post with academic headhunters (I know they're relatively rare, but they *are* used, especially for this kind of post).

Google search reveals firms who are only interested in approaches by institutions.

What are effective strategies for finding and connecting, discreetly, with academic head hunters?

Comment: Well I'm not shopping for a job I'm asking about Headhunters' names. How or where else would you suggest I do so?

Comment: Please see https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold-for-shopping; "shopping" refers to any question where you're looking for a specific product, service, company, etc.  I am afraid I don't have any other suggestions as to where to ask.

Comment: Actually, you are shopping for names. Any sort of shopping is discouraged here.

Comment: Don't people receive notifications of job offers from apps like LinkedIn ?

Comment: Are you looking for a job in administration? (Vice-Chancellor, Dean, Provost, etc.) I get the feeling that the sort of headhunters you've heard of are for those sorts of positions, not regular research/teaching faculty positions.